# Best way for populating JTable with data from SQLite4java

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, jtable, datamodel

I'm using sqlite4java and i want to display the query results in the Table component.
I have made a DataModel and it works by getting each call value as my code shows below, but it is really slow when the query result has 10k or more rows and 10 columns.

```
public Object getValueAt(final int row,final int column) {
   return queue.execute(new SQLiteJob<Object>() {
        @Override
        protected Object job(SQLiteConnection connection) throws SQLiteException {
            Object Result = "";
            SQLiteStatement st = connection.prepare("SELECT * from test LIMIT ?,1 ;");
            st.bind(1, row);
            while (st.step()) {
                Result = st.columnString(column);
            }
            st.dispose();
            return Result;
        }
    }).complete();


}
```

What is the correct way to get this working as fast as possible?

Comment: my question if `SQLite` have got implemented `Paginations`, meaning your code `(SELECT .... LIMIT ?, 1)`

Comment: I dont know what you mean by Paginations,  but SELECT .. LIMIT x,y works fine.

Comment: this SQL connection is only one directional???, only about populating data from SQL engine to the JTable???, or updates in the JTable could be saved into Database immediately???

Comment: at this moment only selecting and displaying the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you will execute a query each time the `getValueAt` method is called (which is called a lot). Typically a database query is not fast enough for usage in this method (certainly not when using a remote database).

A better approach is to query your database once (well, depends a bit on the size of the data you retrieve from your DB), put it in a `TableModel` and build your table using that `TableModel`.

SO contains lots of questions and answers for this problem so a quick search would point you to a lot of sample code. I copied [this link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) from one of those questions. All credits for the code on that page go of course to the author (who is also present here, but I forget his username on SO)

Answer (score 2):

I never touched SqLite, maybe I dis_agree that [Embedded databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) could be too lazy

1. (for hard, hardiest SQL Query) create [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), data for populating `JTable` move to the `BackGroung Tasks`, by using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or `Runnable#Thread` (in this case output to the `DefaultTableModel` must be wrapped into `invokeLater`), there you can use the Paginations by spliting one SQL Query `(... LIMIT int, int)` to a few separated queries and with separate output to the `JTable`
2. for standard query you can use prepared Classes based on `AbstractTableModel` (avoiding to reinvent the wheel) , search for `ResultSetTableModel` or best way would be [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) by @camickr